# Cycle through clients on both screens in awesomewm

Tags: multiple-monitors, application-switcher, awesome, lua

I am using awesomewm and have two monitors, so `Mod4+j` and `Mod4+k` cycle through windows on current screen only. Is there a way to cycle through all windows/clients on all screens to make it work like ordinary `Alt+Tab`?

Answer (score 3):

After poking around [awful module docs](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.client.html) i found a solution. It is hacky, but it works as I wanted it to work.

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "Tab",
    function ()
        awful.client.focus.byidx(1)
        if awful.client.ismarked() then
            awful.screen.focus_relative(-1)
            awful.client.getmarked()
        end
        if client.focus then
            client.focus:raise()
        end
        awful.client.togglemarked()
    end),
```

This function cycles through clients on current screen, marking them and when they all are marked, jumps to the next screen. Here is what happens step by step:

- we focus the next client
- we check if it is marked and if it is, we [move to the next screen](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.screen.html#focus_relative) and [clear marked status from all clients on it](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.client.html#getmarked)
- we raise current client
- and mark it

It is funny because i do not know what "marked" means. Marked clients do not seem to differ from not marked clients visually or by behaviour.

It is strange that i had to write a 10 line function to get something as trivial as multiscreen alt-tab. I might have done something excessive)

Comment: marking seems to allow you to add a tag to marked clients all at once from what i can tell. it's not discussed much in the manpage, but it has one reference to "tag marked clients with tag". what i've picked up on though is you can probably use that "mark" functionality for anything that needs to be applied or processed on multiple clients. say for example you have 10 clients and you want title bars on 4, mark those 4 and then with some lua code you can have it add the titlebars on those you've marked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when this capability was added, but I believe you're looking for

[client.focus.global_bydirection (dir, c)](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.client.html#client.focus.global_bydirection)

*Focus a client by the given direction. Moves across screens.
Parameters:*

- dir: The direction, can be either "up", "down", "left" or "right".
- c: Optional client.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [awesome-cyclefocus module](https://github.com/blueyed/awesome-cyclefocus)

> awesome-cyclefocus is a module/plugin for the awesome window manager, which provides methods to cycle through the most recently used clients (typically known as Alt-Tab).

It allows to easily filter the list of windows to be cycled through, e.g. by screen, tags, window class, name/title etc.